# Azure CICD : PowerShell script task is failing

Tags: sql-server, azure, powershell, azure-devops

I'm not sure what is breaking in the set-up that I'm doing with the Azure CICD pipeline for SQL scripts. As part of this process, I'm using the PowerShell script task to refresh the database on `server1` using the latest backup files from `server2`. This task is failing with the "Access denied" error when the code connects to the `server2` to get the backup files.

```
*Get-ChildItem : Access is denied
at

$getServer2File = Get-ChildItem $Server2Path -Filter *.bak| Sort-Object ...
+ CategoryInfor     : PermissionDenied : (\\server2.xxx.com..*
```

I have a different PowerShell script on `server1` which is working fine. 
I'm not sure why I'm getting "Access denied" error and how to fix this access between all the servers.

Comment: What does this have to do with SQL Server? What is the script you're running? The error appears to be telling you the problem, you don't have access to the directory.

Comment: It seems the command requires Administrator access according to [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ba1dc1a3-0038-455e-a2be-2ea119c8d22b/getchilditem-access-is-denied?forum=winserverpowershell) while the `Powershell script task` does not provide admin access, so you might need to change the task to `Powershell on target machine` which you can refer to [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/85031914-7d40-4a24-8d85-1d1de26fdd71/release-definition-run-task-powershell-as-admin?forum=TFService).

Comment: Thanks, @YangShen-MSFT... I have changed to the Powershell script task and given the username/password who is having admin access. Also added HTTPS listener and enabled firewall exception. Though I have chosen HTTPS, I'm getting the below HTTP error only. Any other setting to be enabled or modified? can you please share your thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: The error is: Unable to create pssession. Error: 'Connecting to remote server "server1" failed with the following error message : The WinRM client sent a request to an HTTP server and got a response saying the requested HTTP URL was not available. This is usually returned by an HTTP server that does not support the WS-Management protocol.
PSSession could not be created for Machine:'server1:5986'

Comment: Not an expert, please check `Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Remote Management\WinRM Service\Allow remote server management through WinRM ` is enabled and it has a * for both IPv4 and IPv6 filter. You can check [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/c7zxxv/issue_with_invokecommand_the_winrm_client_sent_a/) and [this blog](https://rcmtech.wordpress.com/2016/10/21/fix-powershell-winrm-remote-connection-errors/).